# If I switch to mamba from conda how can I preserve existing conda environments

Tags: conda, mamba

I'm thinking of switching to mamba from conda, but don't want to lose my existing conda environments. If I make the switch, how can I preserve my existing conda environments?

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense without more details on what you think "switching to Mamba" entails. Mamba is merely a front-end CLI for interacting with Conda environments and can be installed into an existing Conda **base** (though not Anaconda **base**). Please add details on what you plan to do and what you anticipate would result in losing existing environments.

Comment: Also, be aware that the latest Conda release (v23.09) already runs with `libmamba` as its default solver, so there is no longer an impetus to switch to Mamba for better solve times. There are still some UX advantages with better conflict reporting and advanced tooling for exploring the dependency graph, but most users really just care about the speed. Otherwise, the trend I see among power users is a switch to Micromamba, a **base**-less (static) Conda manager, which is really how `conda` should have been implemented in the first place.

Comment: @merv - I was thinking I'd uninstall conda and install mamba, but confess I'm a little fuzzy on just how different mamba is from conda. Is it a totally different package? A branch off of the current package? Something else? Can mamba use an environment created in conda? Either way, my main concern was faster solving, so it looks like just updating conda will answer my needs.